# Remove method, to remove object from array of objects

Tags: java, methods, foreach, nullpointerexception

So I have a class `Pizza`:

```
public class Pizza{

private final int MAX_INGREDIENTS = 5;
private int id;
private String name;
private String description;
private float price;
private PizzaSize size;
private PizzaIngredients[] ingredients;
private int numberOfIngredients;
}
```

As you can see I have an Enum, `PizzaSize` that isn't relevant for this question.

I also have a `Ingredients` class:

```
public class Ingredients {

private int id;
private String name;
private MeasurementUnits measurementUnits;
private int calories;
}
```

As you can see I have an Enum, `MeasurementUnits` that isn't relevant for this question either.

And lastly, I have a `PizzaIngredients` class:

```
public class PizzaIngredients {

private Ingredients ingredients;
private float quantity;
}
```

All these classes have their respective constructor method and all the Setters and Getters, to save space and potentiate clarity I chose not to put them here.

So I wrote this method to remove an Ingredient from a collection of ingredients by its id:

```
public void removeIngredient(int id) {

if (this.numberOfIngredients > 0) {
    for(int i = 0; i < this.ingredients.length; i++) {
       if (this.ingredients[i] != null && this.ingredients[i].getIngredients().getId() == id) {
          ingredients[i] = null;
       }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Pizza has no ingredients!");
    }
}
```

But now I'm trying to write the method without using and index `i`, using a `foreach`:

```
    if (this.numberOfIngredients > 0) {
        for (PizzaIngredients ing : this.ingredients) {
            if (ing.getIngredients().getId() == id) {
               ing.setIngredients(null);
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Pizza has no ingredients!");
    }
```

This method sets the ingredient to null but when printing it,

```
    pizza1.removeIngredient(1);
    System.out.println("Removing ingredient test (pizza1): ");
    for (PizzaIngredients ingredient : collection1) {
        if (ingredient != null) {
            System.out.println("ID: " + ingredient.getIngredients().getId() + "| Name: " + ingredient.getIngredients().getName()
                    + "| Quantity: " + ingredient.getQuantity() + " " + ingredient.getIngredients().getMeasurementUnits());
        }
    }
```

throws the NullPointerException, while using the method with the index it doesn't. Why is it so? When changing the second method condition to `ing = null` it doesn't even work, it still prints the ingredient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get NullPointerException because you are still trying to access the Ingredient within PizzaIngredient, which you have set to null.

So you are setting the Ingredient to null, here:

```
ing.setIngredients(null);
```

But you are trying to access that same null Ingredient in your system.out, here:

```
ingredient.getIngredients().getId()
```

You should change your if statement to this:

```
if (ingredient.getIngredients() != null) {
```

Comment: No problem.  Glad I could help.